# MySQL - Select all Distinct Rows Except 1

Tags: mysql, distinct

```
select distinct t.id,
t.name,
t.location,
t.country
from table t
```

Say I have a query like this above, where I want only distinct values for all of those select statements, except when the country is 'US', then a want all the values that correspond to that country.  Is that even possible?  Can you select all distinct rows and then include some multiples based on 1 exception?

Comment: I present one answer, but I think you should include sample data in desire output because I dont see how this will be usefull. So I guess your *real* question is different

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want try with `UNION ALL`

```
select distinct t.id,
       t.name,
       t.location,
       t.country
from table t
WHERE country <> 'US'

UNION ALL

select t.id,
       t.name,
       t.location,
       t.country
from table t
WHERE country = 'US'
```